# LinkedIn API: Getting read ECONNRESET error while posting video in multipart

Tags: linkedin-api

While posting videos in multipart, as written in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/community-management/shares/videos-api?view=li-lms-2023-11&tabs=http#how-to-upload-videos), we are getting the error `read ECONNRESET` intermittently, i.e. the server is closing the connection unexpectedly.
This is happening for videos that are greater than 80 MB.
We are doing the multipart uploads asynchronously and we are using the latest version of the LinkedIn Marketing API — November 2023.